# Bad Receiver type 'NSString *_strong *

Tags: objective-c

I have a code that defines every letter in the alphabet (twice, actually). It also sets it to a table. However, it is giving me the error, "Bad Receiver type 'NSString *_strong *"

```
#import "editCodeTable.h"

@implementation editCodeTable

NSString *everything[63];
NSString *everything2[63];

-(void) setEverythings {
    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
        NSString *a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", i+97];
        everything[i]=a;
        everything2[i]=a;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView {
    return 63;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    if ([aTableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"row1"]){
        [self setEverythings];
        return [everything2 objectAtIndex:rowIndex]; //Error message appears here
        }
        return [everything objectAtIndex:rowIndex]; //Error message appears here
}

@end
```

I'm not good with Objective-C, so I don't know where to start to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `everything` and `everything2` aren't `NSArray`s, you can't call `objectAtIndex:` on them.

They are string *collections**, so use this syntax:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    if ([aTableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"row1"]){
        [self setEverythings];
        return everything2[rowIndex];
        }
        return everything[rowIndex];
}
```

<sub>*I like to call them *weird things*</sub>